# How to save tags in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, tags

I'd like to have pretty tags in my form but I can't save it in my database.
When I use the ugly tags way, it works :

```
 = f.input :all_tags, label: 'Tags', placeholder: 'Séparé par une virgule', input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
```

But I would like to have existing tags which allow the user to directly click on it to have it save. Like :

```
.tag
      %input{:type => "checkbox"}/
      %label{:for => ""} Diet
      %i.fa.fa-plus
      %i.fa.fa-check
```

So visually it works, but as you can see I do not say in wich field it's suppose to be saved, and I do not say the value to save either.

Does someone can help me ?

For better understanding I give you the whole form :

recipes/new :

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  - if @recipe.errors.any?
    #errors
      %p
        = @recipe.errors.count
        prohibited this recipe from being saved:
      %ul
        - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  .row
    .panel-body
      = f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      = f.input :description, placeholder: 'Dites nous ce que vous aimez dans cette recette ? où l\'avez-vous découverte ? avec quoi l\'accompagnée vous ? ...', input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      = f.input :image, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      # ugly way
      = f.input :all_tags, label: 'Tags', placeholder: 'Séparé par une virgule', input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      # pretty way
      .tag-wrapper
        .tag
          %input{:type => "checkbox"}/
          %label{:for => ""} Diet
          %i.fa.fa-plus
          %i.fa.fa-check
        .tag
          %input{:type => "checkbox"}/
          %label{:for => ""} Healthy
          %i.fa.fa-plus
          %i.fa.fa-check

      = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"

%script{:src => "https://use.fontawesome.com/6d77a862a3.js"}
```

recipes_controller :

```
def new
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
end

def create
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @recipe.save
      format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image, :all_tags, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions_attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy])
  end
```

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  belongs_to :user

  def all_tags
   self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should go with a multiselect and then do some css to make it more good looking?

Comment: That's a good idea, i'll try that

Comment: I begun slowly, just by transforming the input in multiselect. But it doesn't save in database. 
` = f.input :all_tags, label: 'Tags', collection: Tag.all, input_html: {multiple: true, class: 'form-control'} `

Comment: What about you backend? How you dealing with data in the controller? How tags are stored in the database? Is it a array field, a table through association?

Comment: I edited my post to add some usefull details. It's a through association

Comment: You forget the "value" attribute in the `%input` tag

Comment: Ok so %input{:type => "checkbox", :value => "Diet"}. And then how can I say "save it in the fields 'all_tags' "